# Mocking an variable inside function using mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have problem with mocking testing:

```
from module import FUNC
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.var = FUNC()

  def test(self):
    var_test = self.var.get()
    return var_test
```

Now if I want to test function test() I need to mock var_test so what I'm doing is:

```
def test_test(self):
  with mock.patch('module.FUNC.get') as mo:
    mo.return_value = "var"
    self.assertIn("no", A.test())
```

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to patch the module [where it is used](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6), e.g. if class `A` is in module `module_a`, you have to patch `module_a.FUNC`.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing but it is not working, the problem is within self.var.get() If I moved it to a function and return it I can mock it but since it is self. I'm unable to do that  @MrBeanBremen

Comment: As far as I can see, you have to mock `module.FUNC` and then set `mo.return_value.get.return_value = "var"`, because you need to mock the instance of `FUNC` (e.g. `mo.return_value`).

Answer (score 0):

The target you are trying to patch is probably not correct. For the below example, we should patch the `get` method of `FUNC` class inside `a.py`. So the patch target should be `a.FUNC.get`.

E.g.

`a.py`:

```py
from module import FUNC


class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = FUNC()

    def test(self):
        var_test = self.var.get()
        return var_test
```

`module.py`:

```py
class FUNC(object):
    def get(self):
        pass
```

`test_a.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from a import A


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test(self):
        with mock.patch('a.FUNC.get') as mo:
            mo.return_value = "no"
            a = A()
            self.assertEqual("no", a.test())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
 ⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/64293629/test_a.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                   Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/64293629/a.py            7      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/64293629/module.py       3      1    67%   3
src/stackoverflow/64293629/test_a.py      11      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                     21      1    95%
```